# DotNetZip and Vietnamese Characters in Contents

Tags: encoding, dotnetzip

I've been using DotNetZip for a while but just ran into a problem. I have some text (not the filename but the actual text contents) which includes non-Latin characters (specifically Vietnamese). When I use DotNetZip to zip up this content, every time I unzip it, the text is garbled (changed in a bad way).

```
    Dim strOriginal As String = "Đinh Quỳnh Ngô Nguyễn Phạm Tuấn Vũ Phương Ngọc Châu Trần Thị Ngọc Hồng Hiền Tô"
    Using zip As New Ionic.Zip.ZipFile()
        zip.AlternateEncoding = System.Text.Encoding.Unicode
        zip.AlternateEncodingUsage = Ionic.Zip.ZipOption.Always
        zip.AddEntry("data", strOriginal)
        zip.Save("test.zip")
    End Using

    Dim strContents As String
    Using zip As New Ionic.Zip.ZipFile("test.zip")
        Using ms As New System.IO.MemoryStream()
            zip.Entries(0).Extract(ms)
            ms.Position = 0
            Using sr As New System.IO.StreamReader(ms)
                strContents = sr.ReadToEnd
                sr.Close()
            End Using
            ms.Close()
        End Using
    End Using
    If strOriginal = strContents Then
        MsgBox("Happy")
    Else
        MsgBox("Sad")
    End If
```

I've tried the following Encoding options: UTF7, UTF8, Unicode, UTF32, and BigEndianUnicode. All produce bad results.

Is this a bug or is my implementation off somehow?

In case it matters, I'm using VB.Net 2010, Win7 x64, .Net 3.5, and DotNetZip 1.9.1.8.

Answer (score 1):

I found my own answer. I'll post it here in case anyone in the future is looking for it.

```
Dim strOriginal As String = "Đinh Quỳnh Ngô Nguyễn Phạm Tuấn Vũ Phương Ngọc Châu Trần Thị Ngọc Hồng Hiền Tô"
Using zip As New Ionic.Zip.ZipFile()
    Dim byteArray() As Byte = System.Text.Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(strOriginal)
    zip.AddEntry("data", byteArray)
    zip.Save("test.zip")
End Using

Dim strContents As String
Using zip As New Ionic.Zip.ZipFile("test.zip")
    Using ms As New System.IO.MemoryStream()
        zip.Entries(0).Extract(ms)
        ms.Position = 0
        Using sr As New System.IO.StreamReader(ms, System.Text.Encoding.Unicode)
            strContents = sr.ReadToEnd
            sr.Close()
        End Using
        ms.Close()
    End Using
End Using
If strOriginal = strContents Then
    MsgBox("Happy")
Else
    MsgBox("Sad")
End If
```